# Mongodb find method not returning anything

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I am using the following code to try to find a name. It is also creating it before the find. However, the find method is not returning anything

```
const assert =require('assert');
const User = require('../src/user');

describe('Reading users out of the database',() =>{
  let joe;

  beforeEach(() =>{
    joe = new User({ name: 'Joe'});
    joe.save()
      .then(() => done());
  });
  it('finds all users with a name of joe', (done) => {
    User.find({ name: 'Joe' })
      .then ((users) =>{
        console.log(users);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

My output is in the image below:
[image]
what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. the done was missing in the beforeEach block.